# Why thread terminates before loading all the data?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am using Thread for loading library (Native code ) have to call some functions from the android code to the native code. it's working fine after some time thread terminating, so those functions are not calling properly. present i am using this code for thread creation.

```
class  aThread extends Thread {

  public static boolean finished;

  public void run() {

      if ( a_app.initApp() != 0) {           
        return;
      } else {           
      }
      a_app.startPjsua(ApjsuaActivity.CFG_FNAME);
      finished = true;
      a_app.deinitApp();         
  }
}
```

Is it correct process or not.?
Can i use any service for solving this problem, if yes how to create communication between activity and Service.

My requirement is i have to call a function in the background continuous upto app closes fully.? what is the best way to do like this.

Comment: Do you mean the thread is terminating while the rest of the application is still running? Or after you close the application's activity? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Thread is terminating while the rest of the application was still running.mainly i want to run that thread till the application running on device..

Comment: The I'd expect some error being logged, have you checked the logs? And you're perfectly sure that your thread is not done with the task, right?

Comment: Or do you want to keep calling `a_app.startPjsua(ApjsuaActivity.CFG_FNAME);` repeatedly while your app is running?

Comment: i want to keep calling two functions along with this.a_app.startPjsua(ApjsuaActivity.CFG_FNAME);

Comment: The look at what @Ashwin answered - isn't it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
boolean ok;
onCreate(Bundle a)
{
  ...
  ok=true;
  new aThread().start();
}

    class  aThread extends Thread {

      public static boolean finished;

      public void run() {
         while(ok==true)
         {
           if ( a_app.initApp() != 0) {           
             ok=false;
           } else { 
           a_app.startPjsua(ApjsuaActivity.CFG_FNAME);
           finished = true;
           a_app.deinitApp();           
           }

          //If you want to execute after some interval..
          //Thread.sleep(time_in_milliseconds);

         }
      }
    }
```

This way it will run as long as `ok=true`. When you exit the app or if you want to stop the thread; set the value of `ok=false`.

Comment: i am getting this error if i use above code FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
at :  `if ( a_app.initApp() != 0) { `   line